# How to cherry-pick a HISTORY commit and apply forcedly to current branch

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I wan to use a **reverted history** commit.

Let's say this is my commit tree

`A -> A' -> B -> C -> D`

I made a commit `A` and reverted it by `A'`. Now, I am at `D` and I want my commit tree to be like

`A -> A' -> B -> C -> D -> A''`, where `A''` is as same as `A`.

**To summarize, I want to use a history commit.**

I cannot simply checkout to `A` because I hope `B, C, D` be included.

I tried `git cherry-pick`, but `B, C` have conflicts with `A`.

**My question is**: How should I use `cherry-pick` to transform my commit tree to `A -> A' -> B -> C -> D -> A''`, without solving conflicts manually? (I tried `git cherry-pick -X ours` and `git cherry-pick cd003861 --strategy-option theirs` but failed.)

Comment: There may not be a way to reapply this commit without merge conflicts.

Comment: Git isn't magic; if B, C or D introduced changes that mean A can no longer cleanly be applied, then you will have to resolve that yourself.

Comment: git checkout myhistoryversion -b. then: git merge master.

Comment: Reminder : conflicts are **not** errors.

Comment: As everyone says, "conflicts" (harsh term) is just gits way of asking you for help. One option is that you've resolved those conflicts previously and enabled `rerere`, and taught git how to merge certain changes. But probably rarely does git have all the merge-conflicts-resolution info it needs for your scenario to always succeed.

Theoretically, with `rerere` enabled and prior knowledge of conflict resolution for these concrete cases, it would be possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you all for your swift responses. To clarify, handing **conflicts** manually is impossible in my case, as there are so many files. Therefore, I am seeking approaches similar to ```git push -force```. Seems like there are no ways of doing that.

Comment: Can you explain "I hope B, C, D be included" ?